# Understanding the statement in the One-Sided Hardy-Littledwood maximal inequality

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am having some trouble understanding the *One-Sided Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality*. In **[An introduction to measure theory, T. Tao]** it is stated as follows:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an absolutely integrable unction, and let $\lambda  > 0$. Then
>   $$ m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \sup\limits_{h>0} \frac{1}{h} \int_{[x, x+h]}|f(t)|\>dt \geq \lambda\}) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(t)|\> dt $$

(where $m$ is the lebesgue measure)

What is the theorem actually stating? I'm having some trouble reading the left-hand side of it. And the way in which I am reading it (in my head, I'm having a hard time even writing it down) does not give me much intuition.

So informally, what does the theorem say? It seems quite similar to Markov's inequality.

Comment: The LHS would indeed be more easily understood if it were written $m(\{x\in R :\lambda \geq \sup$... (et cetera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In words, it means that the maximal function is not much larger than $|f|$. (Stein and Shakarchi Real Analysis p.101).

The lefthand side is the measure of the set of values at which the maximal function is larger than a particular real number. Note that as that real number grows to infinity, the RHS goes to zero. So the set on which the maximal function takes infinite values is a set of measure zero. Since $f$ is integrable (i.e. $\int |f|\le \infty$), we know that $|f|=\infty$ on a set of measure zero.

Recall that we're introducing the maximal function because we're hoping to see when the averaging property holds: Is it true that $\lim_{|I|\to 0,\ x\in I} \frac{1}{|I|} \int_I f(y)\,dy=f(x)$? It would have been nice if $f^*$ were integrable; it's not, and the property you cited turns out to be the next best thing (Exercises 4, 5 on p. 146 for a more careful definition).

Comment: Thank you. That actually helped me quite a bit!

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it.